# Redirect Redirecting before Form Forms

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect

I am attempting to work with and learn PHP with forms (with formoid at the moment) and am running into an issue. I'm following the tutorials I've looked at and nothing is working (correctly). I have a simple redirect script that I am intending to use to redirect someone to a page "verified.html" if they enter the correct ID and (six digit) date and to "no.html" if they do not. However, both ways I attempt to do this are not working. When I use this method:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){   
    $id = $_POST['trid'];
    $date = $_POST['trdate'];   
  }

  if ($id == '555555' && $date =='080808') {
    header("Location: http://example.com/Form/verified.html");
    exit();
  }    else {
    header("Location: http://example.com/Form/no.html");
    exit();
  }
 ?>
```

The page redirects to "no.html" before the form even loads. After reading through another tutorial I figured I had to include the two IF statements in the "IF (isset" statement. So if I do that and use this method:

```
 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])){   
    $id = $_POST['trid'];
    $date = $_POST['trdate'];   

    if ($id == '555555' && $date =='080808') {
      header("Location: http://example.com/Form/verified.html");
       exit();
    }  else {
       header("Location: http://example.com/Form/no.html");
       exit();
    }
 }
```

the form will actually load, but it will not redirect anywhere no matter what I type in and submit. I was up all last night working on this and fiddling with different solutions, everything I came up with would either lead to the form not being loaded, or it was loaded and then did not redirect on input. If anyone could point me in the correct direction that would be awesome. Here is the code for the form page if that is relevant (I include the redirect.php at the beginning because if I include it elsewhere I get an error regarding header() already being sent):

```
 <?php
    include "redirect.php";
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Verify</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-   scale=1.0">
 </head>
 <body class="blurBg-false" style="background-color:#EBEBEB">

 <!-- Start Formoid form-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="formoid_files/formoid1/formoid-solid-blue.css" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="formoid_files/formoid1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="validate.php" class="formoid-solid-blue" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;font-family:'Roboto',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#34495E;max-width:480px;min-width:150px" method="post"><div class="title">      <h2>Patient Verification</h2></div>

    <div class="element-input"><label class="title">Please enter the six digit ID below:</label><div class="item-cont"><input class="large" type="text" name="trid" id="trid" placeholder="Input Number"/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>

    <div class="element-input"><label class="title">Please enter the six digit year MMDDYY below:</label><div class="item-cont"><input class="large" type="text" name="trdate" id="trdate" placeholder="Input Number"/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>

    <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div></form>

    <p class="frmd"><a href="http://example.com/v29.php">form builder</a> Formoid.com 2.9</p><script type="text/javascript" src="formoid_files/formoid1/formoid-solid-blue.js"></script>

 <!-- Stop Formoid form-->

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Why you are including the `redirect.php` , why can't you have it in your parent page itself ?

Comment: I would start debugging by dumping the entire `$_POST` array to the screen using `var_dump()` or `print_r()` on form submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looks like your looking is `$_POST['submit']` has been set but you don't have the name="submit" on your button element. Why don't you use...

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){   
   $id = $_POST['trid'];
   $date = $_POST['trdate'];   

if ($id == '555555' && $date =='080808') {
  header("Location: http://example.com/Form/verified.html");
   exit();
}  else {
   header("Location: http://example.com/Form/no.html");
   exit();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, John.  I'm going to test this out on my lunch break.  Funny you should mention naming the submit button.  I did try that last night and it did not work, but I'll try it again and the solution above and see if either or both works (changes were probably made since I did name it).

Comment: Thank you so much, John.  The above solution worked.  Using "input name="submit"" didn't work though, which was puzzling me last night too.

Comment: I don't think you need to check against the submit button. If you want to check again the values your using i would use 'if(isset($_POST['trid'] && isset($_POST['trdate']))) {}'

Answer (score 0):

Replace your form in html page with this:

```
<form action="validate.php" class="formoid-solid-blue" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;font-family:'Roboto',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#34495E;max-width:480px;min-width:150px" method="post"><div class="title">      
    <h2>Patient Verification</h2></div>
    <div class="element-input">
        <label class="title">Please enter the six digit ID below:</label>
            <div class="item-cont">
                <input class="large" type="number" name="trid" id="trid" placeholder="Input Number"/>
                <span class="icon-place"></span>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="element-input">
        <label class="title">Please enter the six digit year MMDDYY below:</label>
        <div class="item-cont">
            <input class="large" type="number" name="trdate" id="trdate" placeholder="Input Number"/>
            <span class="icon-place"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

and php with this:

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){  

        $id = $_POST['trid'];
        $date = $_POST['trdate'];   

        if ($id == '555555' && $date =='080808') {
          header("Location: http://example.com/Form/verified.html");

        }  else {
           header("Location: http://example.com/Form/no.html");

        }
    }
?>
```

Check this out and let me know the results.

Comment: Hi choxx, thank you for taking the time.  John's solution worked and I went with it but I did test yours.  Adding name="submit" doesn't work, and I don't know why.  I did replace the code with you're solution and it does not work - it removes the styling.  It simply refreshes the page and does not redirect.

Comment: @user4333011 The code I gave above is absolutely working. See, I have edited validate.php and commented headers and insert alert box to check the redirection based on condition matching from form values. Visit this link, I have created for your clarification: http://www.geekzgarage.com/test/

Comment: One more thing, what I had edited in your form is the type of input tags for trid and trdate(thinking that you are taking them as number) and code indentation. You may again change input types as text, no problem in that. NO OTHER STYLING DONE BY ME IN YOUR FORM EXCEPT STATED ABOVE.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){   
    $id = $_POST['trid'];
    $date = $_POST['trdate'];   
}

global $id, $date;

if ($id == '555555' && $date =='080808') {
    header("Location: http://example.com/Form/verified.html");
    exit();
} else {
    header("Location: http://example.com/Form/no.html");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: This goes back to the original problem of the page always redirecting, even if the form hasn't been submitted yet. Also the use of `global` is not doing anything to help in this case, and in general tends to be a bad practice.